# Intersection of two T-SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have two results of queries:

Query #1:

```
SELECT title 
FROM operations
```

Output:

```
    +------------+
    |   title    |
    +------------+
    | operation1 |
    | operation2 |
    | operation3 |
    | operation4 |
    +------------+
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT o.title 
FROM role_operation ro 
INNER JOIN roles r ON ro.role_id = r.id 
INNER JOIN operations o ON ro.operation_id = o.id 
WHERE r.title = N'role1'
```

Output:

```
    +------------+
    |   title    |
    +------------+
    | operation1 |
    | operation3 |
    | operation4 |
    +------------+
```

Is it possible to return intersection of results in separate column? Something like this:

```
    +------------+----------+
    |   title    | isExists |
    +------------+----------+
    | operation1 |     1    |
    | operation2 |     0    |
    | operation3 |     1    |
    | operation4 |     1    |
    +------------+----------+
```

I was trying to use `INTERSECT` operator on queries, but it returns only intersected rows. What should be done to know intersection state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a left join:

```
SELECT    o.title, CASE WHEN ro.role_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS role_exists
FROM      operations
LEFT JOIN role_operator operations ro ON ro.operation_id = o.id 
LEFT JOIN roles r ON ro.role_id = r.id AND r.title = N'role1'
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen nice catch! should have folded it in to the `join` condition.

Comment: Your original answer was still much better than mine ^ ^.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want:

```
SELECT o.title, (CASE WHEN r.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as isexists
FROM operations o LEFT JOIN
     role_operation ro 
     ON ro.operation_id = o.id LEFT JOIN
     roles r
     ON ro.role_id = r.id AND r.title = N'role1';
```

My only confusion is that you use the term "intersection" to describe what you want.  "Intersection" means the things common two the two queries.  What you want does combine the queries, but it is in no way an "intersection".

Comment: In my mind intersection means that if two queries have the same result rows, than return 1 else return 0.

Comment: @developer . . . That is not what "intersection" means in the mathematics of set theory or relational algebra.